# Predicate method returns duplicate prompt in case of yes / no / otherwise answer for no answer

Tags: java, while-loop

Am currently following the book called "The Art and Science of Java" by Erik Roberts. 
When testing yes / no / alternate answers in the code, I am getting the question asked twice for the no answer.

```
/*
 * File: YesNoQuestion.java
 * ------------------------
 * This program asks the user a question and expects a yes / no
 * answer. It is also exercise 7 in Chapter 5.
 * "Write a predicate method askYesNoQuestion(prompt) that prints 
 * the string prompt as a question for the user and then waits 
 * for a response. If the user enters the string "yes", the 
 * askYesNoQuestion method should return true; if the user enters 
 * "no", the method should return false. If the user enters 
 * anything else, askYesNoQuestion should remind the user that it 
 * is seeking a yes-or-no answer and then repeat the question."
 */

import acm.program.*;

public class YesNoQuestion extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run () {
        String prompt = "Are you over 18 year old?";
        if (askYesNoQuestion(prompt) == true) {
            println("Evaluated true.");
        }
        else if (askYesNoQuestion(prompt) == false) {
            println ("Evaluated false");
        }
    }
/* Predicate method returns true if user enters the string "yes"
 * and false if the user enters "no", else informs user that it is 
 * expecting a yes or no answer.    
 */
    private boolean askYesNoQuestion(String prompt) {
        String userInput = readLine(prompt);
        boolean trueOrFalse = true;
        while(true) {
            if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
                trueOrFalse = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                trueOrFalse = false;
                break;
            }
            else {
                println("Please answer yes or no");
                userInput = readLine(prompt);
            }
        }
        return trueOrFalse;
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the output. Can anyone help me understand why?
[Screenshoted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy1cO.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
if (askYesNoQuestion(prompt) == true) {
    println("Evaluated true.");
}
else if (askYesNoQuestion(prompt) == false) {
    println ("Evaluated false");
}
```

we can see that you are calling `askYesNoQuestion(prompt)` twice. Each time you call it, it asks the question and gets another response from the user.

Just call it once:

```
if (askYesNoQuestion(prompt) == true) {
    println("Evaluated true.");
} else {
    println("Evaluated false.");
}
```

If the `if` condition doesn't match, then the method must have returned false, so there is no need to call the method again and get another result.

Also, the normal way to test a boolean value in a statement is like this:

```
if (askYesNoQuestion(prompt)) {
    ...
```

The `==true` part is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Just a little bit of interpretation here, since i don´t know what `readLine`does, but i guess it promps with a question.

So now lets check the logic. You are going inside the `if` statment. You execute the `readLine` method, which i assume, outputs the question followed by an input. You input `no`. So now your `if` clause eveluates to `false`.

Following now you are going into the `else if` part, where you are doing the same (the method `askYesNoQuestion` gets executed again, which prompts the question and wants an input).

You might want to execute `askYesNoQuestion` before the condition and store it inside a variable and check this variable inside your condition.

```
String prompt = "Are you over 18 year old?";
boolean answer = askYesNoQuestion(prompt);
if (answer) { // you can leave out the == true. It´s shorter and has the same meaning.
    println("Evaluated true.");
} else{ // You don´t need an else if here, since the other state of the boolean is false.
    println ("Evaluated false");
}
```